# Type casting between two different classes

Tags: java

I have a class `Propositions` which is an array list of class

`Proposition`: I want to make a tree, whose Nodes are from class
`ConstituentSet` or `Proposition`. In the Tree just leaves are from
class `Proposition` and all the internal Nodes are from class
`ConstituentSet`.

I do not know how should I define the type of
children in class `ConstituentSet`. If I define from type
`ConstituentSet`, I can not set my leafs in this Type(because they are
from `Proposition`) and if I set the children from type `Proposition`,
I cannot set my internal nodes.

```
public class  ConstituentSet<T> {       
    protected ConstituentSet<T> child1, child2;    
    //OR       
    protected Proposition child1,child2;
}

public class Proposition { 
    private  Property property;
    private Rating       rating;  
    private Type         type;  
    private Serializable value;
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details about `Proposition`.

Comment: Do you need this to do in Java? Sounds like a functional language with algebraic data types would be the proper tool here.

Comment: Don't ruin previous edited posts.

Answer (score 6):

Let your `Propositions` and `ConstituentSet` implement a common *interface*, and then constitute a tree from the instances of this interface.

Comment: +1. And for the record: This is called [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

implement an interface

```
public interface TreeElement(){
     // define methods
}
```

and implement both `Proposition` as `ConstituentSet` with this interface

```
public class constituentSet implements TreeElement{
     protected ArrayList<TreeElement> children;
     // rest of code here
}

public class Proposition implements TreeElement{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: but in interface I should know the type of return value for methods. e.g. I should determine "Proposition getChild()" method or "ConsituentSet getChild()" .